# How to determine when files are done copying for further processing?

Tags: c++, windows, file, filesystems

Alright so to start this is strictly for Windows and I'd prefer to use C++ over .NET but I'm not opposed to `boost::filesystem` although if it can be avoided in favor of straight Windows API I'd prefer that.

Now the scenario is an application on another machine I can't change is going to create files in a particular directory on the machine that I need to make backups of and do some extra processing.  Currently I've made a little application which will sit and listen for change notifications in a target directory using `FindFirstChangeNotification` and `FindNextChangeNotification` windows APIs.

The problem is that while I can get notified when new files are created in the directory, modified, size changes, etc it only notifies once and does not specifically tell me which files.  I've looked at `ReadDirectoryChangesW` as well but it's the same story there except that I can get slightly more specific information.

Now I can scan the directory and try to acquire locks or open the files to determine what specifically changed from the last notification and whether they are available for further use but in the case of copying a large file I've found this isn't good enough as the file won't be ready to be manipulated and I won't get any other notifications after the first so there is no way to tell when it's actually done copying unless after the first notification I continually try to acquire locks until it succeeds.

The only other thing I can think of that would be less hackish would be to have some kind of *end* token file but since I don't have control over the application creating the files in the first place I don't see how I'd go about doing that and it's still not ideal.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fairly common problem and one that doesn't have an easy answer.  Acquiring locks is one of the best options when you cannot change the thing at the remote end.  Another I have seen is to watch the file at intervals until the size doesn't change for an interval or two.

Other strategies include writing a no-byte file as a trigger when the main file is complete and writing to a temp directory then moving the complete file to the real destination.  But to be reliable, it must be the sender who controls this.  As the receiver, you are constrained to watching the directory and waiting for the file to settle.

Comment: I briefly toyed with the idea of a timeout with file growth but it seemed worse than the lock requests.  Maybe I'm naively optimistic that there is a solution that doesn't involve polling.

Comment: The problem is the local OS cannot tell the difference between a successful end-of-file versus an abandoned or interrupted copy so it doesn't even try. Even the polling for locks method isn't foolproof because an interrupted copy will result in a lost lock and when it resumes the file could already have been backed up.  Since WMQ FTE is one of the products I specialize in I see this a lot and on many platforms.  Turns out to be a non-trivial problem.

Comment: That is also an excellent point I didn't even think of that possibility.

Comment: +1 for the no-byte signal file strategy, and the copy-then-move strategy.  Both very common in batch/shell scripts.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like ReadDirectoryChangesW is going to be your best bet. For each file copy operation, you should be receiving FILE_ACTION_ADDED followed by a bunch of FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED notifications. On the last FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED notification, the file should no longer be locked by the copying process. So, if you try to acquire a lock after each FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED of the copy, it should fail until the copy completes. It's not a particularly elegant solution, but there doesn't seem to be any notifications available for when a file copy completes.

Comment: The problem seems to be the caching mechanism of the file system at least in Windows 7 in my testing. I only get one `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE` very shortly after the `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION`. It also seems to create the destination file at the full size even though the copy is not complete so there is only one `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE` firing as well. I may need to create a worker thread to call `ReadDirectoryChangesW` to avoid losing notifications but with how long this operation takes I would expect to get more than one even with the current implementation.

Comment: @AJG85 your observation is correct, first file size is set during copying (at least by explorer) then the data is written.

Answer (score 0):

You can process the data once the file is closed, right? So the task is to track when the file is closed. This can be done using file system filter driver. You can write your own or you can use our [CallbackFilter](http://www.eldos.com/cbflt/filesystemwatcher-vs-callbackfilter.php) product.

Comment: Do you have a reference link with more information about the file system filter driver so I can determine if this is something worth implementing? This sounds like intercepting system internals and thus beyond the scope of effort for this project's time constraints.

Comment: AJG85 indeed if you want to implement your own filter, it would take months of work. Here's information on filters: http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/filterdrv/default.mspx